# Angular: combine animation with a scope change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

Just want to see  some code? Here you go: [some code](http://plnkr.co/8GoYYXpVmYYf2qKp5u8N)

---

My question is, using Angular how do I combine a change in some data on the page, triggered by a click, with a fade in/fade out animation?

I can have a click change content and I can have a click animate but I don't seem to be able to get the two to work together.

Specifically, I want a click that changes a character to the next one in a list but I want the characters to fade in and out as they swap, rather than simply change in place.

[Here is a plunk demonstrating the two behaviors functioning separately](http://plnkr.co/8GoYYXpVmYYf2qKp5u8N). Check it out and if you can suggest how to make the characters swap with a fade in/fade out rather than their current instant change I will be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a non-standard (not part of the ng-animate paradigm) animation in angular. I recommend writing a simple directive.  Ultimately you need to `$watch` for the change and then fire animation code. Because animation code is dom manipulation, it belongs in a directive. Consider an implementation of your directive that would look something like this:

```
  <div cross-fade="currentchar" ></div>
```

Such a directive, could also leverage your existing `.animation` script via [`$animator`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.%24animator)

Comment: Glad to be of service.